# How to view if python is running in console or in shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-idle

So I am currently writing a python program that makes use of the

```
getpass.getpass()
```

function, however this doesn't work in IDLE shell, just console/terminal, so is there anyway to view if I am running a program in python shell or in console/terminal. So if that was so I could do something like:

```
if python == 'console':
    a = getpass.getpass()

elif python == 'idle':
    a = input()
```

It would be incredibly useful if you could, so hopefully you can.

Comment: `sys.stdout.isatty()` may do the trick.

Comment: That appears to always be returning true, even if ran from console.

Comment: *however this doesn't work in IDLE shell*, what does it do or not do in IDLE?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I couldn't quite understand.

Comment: `getpass` may be reaching around to the controlling terminal for input. Add a password hint such as `getpass.getpass("Password: ")` and see if that ends up on the terminal you executed idle from. You can enter it there.

Comment: Yeah I eventually just did that. Kind of annoying that I can't have hidden text in shell

Comment: Answer below, comment here: `getpass.getpass` *does* work in IDLE, using `getpass.fallback_getpass`; it just doesn't hide entered text. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/getpass.py for the OS specific gyrations required to hide text in system terminals.

Comment: Well thanks. This does what I wanted to do but only adds 1 word.

Comment: However is there any way to get getpass not to raise alot of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import sys; 'idlelib' in sys.modules` will be true when running from IDLE, and not when running from a terminal (unless your program imports it).